# Linear equation with integer solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, diophantine-equations

I was reading about linear Diophantine equation of the form:

ax+by+cz=0

The equation has infinitely many integer solutions x,y,zϵZ as long as the coefficients a,b,c are integer numbers. Could someone refer me to an article, book or other source where the equation is treated without the assumption that the coefficients are integers?

Thanks for any helpful references.

Comment: Do you just want to know when it has integer solutions in general, or do you want a "full treatment" of everything one might wan to know?

Comment: Im primarly interested in the conditions the coefficients a,b,c have to fulfill in order for the equations to have integer solutions, although I don't mind learning the full treatment of group of equations of this kind. The more knowledge the better. I just couldn't find a place where general form of the coefficients would be allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coefficients are rationally related to each other you can multiply by a constant to make them all integers.  For example you can go from
$$\sqrt 2 x + \frac 32\sqrt 2 y + \sqrt 8 z=0$$ to
$$2x+3y+4z=0$$
so nothing is lost in assuming the coefficients are integers.

If they are not rationally related you need a very special relationship between them.  For example
$$x+\sqrt 2 y +(\sqrt 2-1)z=0$$ does have integer solutions, but you cannot clear the irrationals by multiplication/division.  We could come up with cases that were not so obvious.  I am not aware of study of these cases because we then are solving in the reals, not the integers.